# Javascript Google Chrome desktop notification

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to create a Javascript script that makes a new Google desktop notification every 10 seconds but my webpage constantly loads and spams notifications. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function timedout(){
    webkitNotifications.createNotification("", "title", "mmm").show();
    setTimeout(timedout(), 10000);
}

timedout();
</script>
```

Please help :(

Comment: You shouldn't have the parenthesis on the `timedout` in the `setTimeout` - that calls it. You just want to pass the refernce.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
function timedout(){ ... }
setInterval(timedout, 10000);
```

Your code calls timedout() immediately (twice) instead of trying to run it every 10 seconds.

Comment: note the timedout() -> timedout in your settimer you send the result of timedout() to the timeout vs the function itself :P

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for setInterval/setTimeout have to be the function name without (), or a string containing the code that will be eval'd. For your use, you can use setInterval which will call the function every X milliseconds.

```
function timedNotification() {
    webkitNotifications.createNotification("", "title", "mmm").show();
}

setInterval("timedNotification()", 10000);
```

Comment: You might as well provide `setInterval(timedNotification, 10000);` as an example.